# How would I be able to invert a string of integers?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to invert the string `"10010"` into `"01101"`. I figured I could try to use the `gsub` method as shown in a similar example in the ruby documentation guides:

```
`"10010".gsub(/[10]/ "1" => "0", "0" => "1")` .
```

However this is not the case. The argument for `gsub` I believe is incorrect. By my logic I'm capturing an INTEGER 1 and 0 not the string, but I'm not too sure how to go about this. Is there a way to perhaps substitute the numbers such as .push/.pop and then change the integer to a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change any `0` into `1`, and viceversa, there is no need of `gsub`, the [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-tr) method is simpler and faster for the purpose:

```
'1010'.tr('10', '01')
# => "0101"

'10010'.tr('10', '01')
# => "01101"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your approach works, you're just missing a comma:

```
"10010".gsub(/[01]/, "1" => "0", "0" => "1")
#=> 01101
```

Answer (score 3):

While you can kinda use `gsub`, do it the right way and twiddle the bits:

```
("10010".to_i(2) ^ 0xff).to_s(2) # => "11101101"
```

Using `gsub` results in an incorrect answer, because `01101` is not the same as inverting the bits of an 8-bit number:

```
'01101'.to_i(2) # => 13
'11101101'.to_i(2) # => 237
```

This might help you understand what's happening:

```
'%08b' % 0x55 # => "01010101"
'%08b' % 0xff # => "11111111"
'%08b' % 0xaa # => "10101010"

'%08b' % (0x55 ^ 0xff) # => "10101010"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about efficiency (as you would read the string thrice):

```
irb(main):004:0> puts "10010".gsub("1", "X").gsub("0", "1").gsub("X", "0")
01101
```

As for your approach, are you sure you aren't missing a comma?

```
irb(main):004:0> puts "10010".gsub("1", "X").gsub("0", "1").gsub("X", "0")
01101
```